# python selenium, i can't find element class or id from a text box

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

i need some help here,
i try to fill a text box
but when i inspect the element then copy the xpath it's only give me

```
/body/html
```

then, i try to use the class name, but it's doesn not work

how i can solve this?

here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('link_to_the_website')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/body/html').send_keys('hello world')

textboxes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
```

here is the html code when i inspect the text box

```
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" class="textarea from-control wysihtml5-editor placeholder" spellcheck="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); cursor: text; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 16.5px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none solid rgb(0, 0, 0); text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px;" contenteditable="true">type here......</body>
```

Comment: You didn't share a link to the web page or at least the HTML. How do you think we can know that element locator?

Comment: OK, please see if my answer resolved your problem

Comment: _in that link we'll see several the text boxes_ - which textarea you want to send the keys ?

Comment: Almost all the textarea in the page is inside an iframe. But without knowing your desired textarea one can only guess.

Comment: yeah, then i want to fill or write in there text area.

there are several text boxes. i want to fill in sequence one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The element you are trying to access is inside iframe.
2. You should use explicit waits
3. Your locator is wrong...
   This may work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('link_to_the_website')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)[1]")))
textarea = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.textarea")))
textarea.send_keys(your_text)
```

**UPD**
The second text area is inside another iframe, but since these are not nested iframes in order to switch to the second iframe from the first iframe you need to switch out from the first iframe to the default content and then to switch into the second iframe.
Generally, after switching into iframe once you finished dealing with elements inside that iframe you shall switch to the default content.
So to write texts to 2 text areas your code may be something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('link_to_the_website')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)[1]")))
textarea1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.textarea")))
textarea1.send_keys(your_text1)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)[2]")))
textarea2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.textarea")))
textarea2.send_keys(your_text2)
```

Comment: Sir it's really works.!

but still having problem to fill the second text box till to the last text box.  i try to change this value    before is "(//iframe)[1]") become  "(//iframe)[2]").

Comment: wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"(//iframe)[2]")))
textarea2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.textarea")))
textarea2.send_keys('your_text2')

Comment: This is actually a new, additional question. See my updated answer. In case it resolved your problem please accept it

Comment: the new one of code you given, it's really works. then i start to understand how it work actually.

thank you so much for helping me.! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you right click and inspect element, try to look if it has a name first and use `driver.find_element_by_name("")` accordingly.

if no name is available, the next stop should be to find the element by css-selector `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("")`.

Xpath is usually the last thing you'd like to use.
Incidentally, the link you provided does have a xpath when I copy it. It would be `/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/input[1]`

Comment: yes sir, but when i try to copy the xpath or full xpath the paste it. i just got /body/html/.

i also already trying to find by it's name, but it's also does not work.